# Toggling select box error states based on user selections/option availability

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

If the user duplicates a selection(s) based on availability being 1 `availableSessions` the select boxes should be highlighted. My problem is I'm not sure how to remove the highlights if the user selects a different option to remove duplication? Ideally I would like to individually remove an error per selection incase the user has duplicated multiple times? Basically the user should be able to continue duplicating but be warned by the error highlights.

Here is the `onSessionSelect` method that handles this logic right now

```
onSessionSelect: function(event) {

        var $currentTarget  = $(event.currentTarget),
            classId = $currentTarget.val(),
            availableSessions = this.model.get('availableSessions');


        var selectedOption = this.$el.find('.js-sessions-select option[value="'+classId+'"]:selected'),
            len = selectedOption.length;       

        if(len > availableSessions) {
            selectedOption.parent().addClass('error');
        } else {
            selectedOption.parent().removeClass('error');
        }
    }
```

Here is an example of the data that is being used to populate each of the select options

```
var availableClassesData = [{
    "id": 34,
    "name": "Core Evo"
}, {
    "id": 686,
    "name": "Core Body Workout"
}, {
    "id": 870,
    "name": "Boxercise"
}, {
    "id": 1345,
    "name": "Rapid Circuits"
}];
```

and here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/u3tdtdhz/

Answer (score 0):

As you've realised, you can't maintain a the correct highlight state throughout all your elements within the context of just the last option changed. Don't restrict your error logic to the last selected option, but rather, clear all the errors at the start of your session select, and write some code to highlight all options that are duplicated.

Comment: Hey, the problem with clearing all the errors means that I would removing all the highlights and that could be for multiple duplications, the user may have duplicated on different items

Comment: That's fine (and actually the point), your error highlighting function should go through and re-highlight all that needs to be highlighted.

Comment: How can I go through all the items then and make the correct highlights after doing the clear? Sorry I'm jus being confused right now

Comment: Well, the most basic way would be: Retrieve all the values from the options and note down the duplicated values, go through all the options with these duplicated values and highlight them.